# implementing jquery datatable using json data

Tags: jquery, json, datatables

I have a method in my controller class that returns json data and it is in the following format

```
[  
   {  
      "userRoleMappingTO":{  
         "userRoleMappingId":1,
         "applicationId":1,
         "userId":194,
         "roleId":1,
         "smartwcmTreeId":1
      },
      "roleTO":{  
         "roleId":1,
         "roleName":"Consumer",
         "applicationId":1
      },
      "userTO":{  
         "userId":194,
         "applicationId":"pgm-apn",
         "username":"joe.antony",
         "password":"password1",
         "email":"joey@gmail.com",
         "firstName":"Joey",
         "lastName":"Anto",
         "enabled":true,
         "userCreated":"sitepmadm",
         "userModified":"sitepmadm",
         "createdTime":1423755723104,
         "updatedTime":1423755961440
      }
   },
   {  
      "userRoleMappingTO":{  
         "userRoleMappingId":2,
         "applicationId":1,
         "userId":189,
         "roleId":2,
         "smartwcmTreeId":1
      },
      "roleTO":{  
         "roleId":2,
         "roleName":"Contributor",
         "applicationId":1
      },
      "userTO":{  
         "userId":189,
         "applicationId":"pgm-apn",
         "username":"test.user",
         "password":"password1",
         "email":"test.user@test.com",
         "firstName":"newuser",
         "lastName":"usertest",
         "enabled":true,
         "userCreated":"sitepmadm",
         "userModified":"sitepmadm",
         "createdTime":1423490983028,
         "updatedTime":1423490983028
      }
   }
]
```

I am trying to display this data as a datatable and the only fields I would require are **userId,username, roleName applicationId**

I normally initialize the datatable as follows

```
 $('#example').dataTable({

            "ajax": {
                    "url": "/the url",
                    "dataSrc":  "",
                    },

            "columns":[
            {"data": "userId"},
            {"data": "applicationId"},
            {"data": "username"},
            {"data": "roleName"},
            ],
            });
```

What changes do I need to make to get the correct data displayed in my table

Answer (score 2):

Your DataTables initialization code should be changed to:

```
$('#example').DataTable({
    "ajax": {
        "url": "/the url",
        "dataSrc": ""
    },
    "columns": [
       {"data": "userTO.userId"},
       {"data": "userTO.applicationId"},
       {"data": "userTO.username"},
       {"data": "roleTO.roleName"}
    ]  
});
```

where [dataSrc](http://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.dataSrc) set to empty string allows you to return plain array and dotted notation in [columns.data](http://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.data) property allows to access nested objects.

See [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0w9k32kr/2/) for demonstration.